# Is there a signal or anything similar to a "pre_select" in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I'm creating a system in django and it'd be really helpful to have a signal that is called every time a SQL "select" query is done on the database. In other words, does anyone know if there is something like a "pre_select" or "post_select" signal method?

I found the signal "connection_created" in the django docs, but couldn't find any clues of how to use it and less about accessing the model that called it. The official documentation just say that it exists but don't give a simple using example... =/

EDIT:
The connection_created just works when the connection is created (how its name says), so, I still without a solution =/.

An example of what I want would be the execution of this queries on distinct objects:

```
ExampleObject1.objects.filter(attribute=somevalue)
ExampleObject2.objects.filter(attribute=somevalue)
ExampleObject3.objects.filter(attribute=somevalue)
```

So a function is called receiving the data from each them just before each query being sent to the database in order to threat data, log, etc.
I imagine that exists some functionality like that in django because django log system appears to use something alike.

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide more information which "select" this is about and what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: I edited it. Is it understandable now? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://dabapps.com/blog/logging-sql-queries-django-13/

It's not in the form of signal, but it allows you to track all queries. Tracking specific selects should be doable by providing customized log handlers.

```
import logging
l = logging.getLogger('django.db.backends')
l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
l.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

#make your queries now...
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for taking so long to answer, I've been really busy lately. =/